# django views can't access webkitformboundary

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

i'm trying to send data with ajax to django views here's my js code

```
messageSENDER.onsubmit = () => {
    formdata = new FormData(messageSENDER);
    $.ajax({
        headers: {"X-CSRFToken": document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value,},
        method: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        ContentType: false,
        data: formdata,
        url : '/send/message/',
        success: function(m){
            messageSENDER.reset()
        }
    })
}
```

in the view function this is the data i get

```
<QueryDict: {'------WebKitFormBoundaryvME3ZcSodJ0Wyw6a\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': ['"csrfmiddlewaretoken"\r\n\r\n7bsMDcWw2yme8P4FC7cEVnkrOuYLR22HFiyrxv9yTOE8rZzZkLta8DvKuf4SNMjt\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryvME3ZcSodJ0Wyw6a\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="partnerPK"\r\n\r\n2\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryvME3ZcSodJ0Wyw6a\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="content"\r\n\r\nmessage content\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryvME3ZcSodJ0Wyw6a\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="files"; filename=""\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryvME3ZcSodJ0Wyw6a--\r\n']}>
```

so how to access it's data the view is working just fine with normal html form and postman but not with ajax

```
def CreateMessage(request):
    pk = request.POST.get('partnerPK')
    text = request.POST.get('content')
    partner = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    m = Message.objects.create(content=text, receiver = partner, sender=request.user)
```

when i try to print any of the data it says either None or gives empty array